# How can I get a method name with the namespace & class name?

Tags: c#, reflection

I'd like to get the fully qualified method name. I can see how to get the method name on its own with the following:

```
System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name
```

but this only returns the actual name. I need everything, like:

```
My.Assembly.ClassName.MethodName
```

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Try

```
var methodInfo = System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod();
var fullName = methodInfo.DeclaringType.FullName + "." + methodInfo.Name;
```

Answer (score 23):

You probably want the [GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.memberinfo.declaringtype.aspx), which returns a [Type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.aspx) object that holds information about the class which declares the method. Then you can use [FullName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.fullname.aspx) property to get the namespace.

```
var currentMethod = System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod();
var fullMethodName = currentMethod.DeclaringType.FullName + "." + currentMethod.Name;
```